# MAUI clang: error: no such file or directory when build iOS Project

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

I Create a MaUI project, and edit **Project Properties** -> **Build** -> **Additional arguments**
[image]

```
-cxx -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir}/lib -lopencv_world490, -force_load ${ProjectDir}/lib/libopencv_world490.a"
```

When build, it occurs error as follows:

```
/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.4.7132/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(3,3): Error: clang++ exited with code 1:
clang: error: no such file or directory: '${ProjectDir}/lib/libopencv_world490.a'
```

I also put the **lib** folder inside three places inside project, it can not work.

[image]

I want to build success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to build successfully, however there will be new problem to use the method from .a library.

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/20136

Finally, we have found the cause that the **.a** can not be used.
No matter what,
replace `{PrjectDir}/lib` with `(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/Platforms/iOS/lib` works for me.

This solution based on the **lib** folder inside **Platforms/iOS**.

And if the **.a** related to other resource files, you will need to add these files(such as: **.bundle**) inside `Resources/raw`.

We also found that the VS for Mac when using MAUI is quite unstable. Such as when editting `.csproj`, the other build settings will be auto-changed in UI Settings of **Projecr Properties**. Amazing!

Good luck for you, guys.